# My computer has gone insane

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I'm really at a loss here. I'm running Windows 10 64 bit, XAMPP version 5.6.36. I've done everything the same as always, haven't changed any files. Suddenly today I tried to refresh a page on localhost and got this error:
"PHP socket: unable to connect [10048]: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

When trying to load a page, about 30% of the time I'd get this error. At one point phpMyAdmin suddenly froze, I refreshed the page and it became a blank screen with a list of error messages about failing to connect. After ~45 seconds it resumed working as normal.

This is so strange. Does anyone have an idea what's happening?

---

Edit: The error messages alternate between the PHP socket error and this:
"mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

It's the exact same page, either working as normal or showing different error messages. This has been going on about 3 hours now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033618/php-socket-unable-to-connect-10048-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-pr Sounds like you may be having a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is quite different. Their issue was caused by their script... My issue came OUT OF NOWHERE.

Comment: did you have updates? which windows 10 build you had? also, does the mysql running properly? last windows update that adds ASLR i noticed breaks a lot open source binaries.. you can configure it through Windows Defender Security Dashboard > App and Browser Console > Exploit Protection Setting (on the right side, bottom). Add a Program Settings that disable *ASLR (Bottom Up)* for `mysql` and `mysqld` -- or you could turn off ASLR entirely, but i wont advise it as a solution.

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with your MySQL configuration.

Comment: @Barmar, are you trying to say the configuration randomly changed itself 3 hours ago, after working with 0 issues for months?

Comment: @Bagus, it's build 17134.165. I did update a week ago, but that wouldn't explain why things would suddenly go haywire now. I'll try those settings though.

Comment: the reason is, some binaries are not compiled to support ASLR and they had some kind of hacks in place for performance (or something else). and it end up breaking things. last time i got issue with `git` (version 2.18) due to this update bringing ASLR.

Comment: Incidentally, mysql_connect was deprecated a long, long time ago

Comment: @Strawberry the OP's php and mysql are old.

Comment: @Shadow I know. Might be time for an upgrade.